# Why does this Knockout binding not work?

Tags: knockout.js

I don't understand why the top binding does not work, but the statement "with" does work.

[I have set up the question on JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyjoyce/6zzEA/4/).

```
Why does this not appear when it is bound to Info.Title?
<div data-bind="text: Info.Title"></div>

<hr/>
But this does when I use the with statement?
<div data-bind="with: Info">
    <div>
         <h1 data-bind="text: Title"></h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first binding is bound to the `Title` property (which is undefined) of the `Info` observable. When the ajax call is done, the `Info` object is *replaced* - `Info.Title` is no longer the same `Info.Title` that was originally bound.

Within the `with:`-scope, however, I believe that the bindings in that scope are re-evaluated when the `Info` observable is changed, therefore the new `Title` is re-bound correctly.

To amend this, you need to not replace `Info`, but have its observables updated when the ajax is done. Also, `Info` does not need to be an observable itself. Here's an edited fiddle with a suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/PQkJb/

Comment: Could you please provide the forked, updated version of your answer (the JS Fiddle link in your answer is my original code), thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your Info property is undefined when the binding happens initially. I updated to add a method to your VM that checks if Info is populated and then returns the Title. Here's the updated example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zzEA/6/). The updated binding code is this, calling the VM function:

```
<div data-bind="text: GetTitle()"></div>
```

The updated VM looks like this, note the function added at the end:

```
function DareDetailViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Info = ko.observable();

    var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
        format: "json"
    })
    .done(function (data) 
    {
        self.Info(new MapInfo(data));
        console.log(data);
    });

    self.GetTitle = function() {
        if(self.Info())
            return self.Info().Title();
    };
};
```

Another option is to initialize your Info property with an object that also has an initial Title. But that seems the longer way to do it so I didn't. :)